# Thinkpad T495s suspend issue

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, power-management, thinkpad

I'm running kubuntu 19.10, fresh install.

When I try to suspend my laptop (menu, closing lid..) sometimes (2/5 aprox.) screen shuts down but fan goes to full speed and laptop gets quite hot, until I force shutdown with power button.

Any idea?

kern.log (interesting lines)

```
Apr  5 15:01:41 medusa kernel: [31828.567162] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ib_ring_tests [amdgpu]] *ERROR* IB test failed on gfx (-22).
Apr  5 15:01:41 medusa kernel: [31828.567248] [drm:amdgpu_device_delayed_init_work_handler [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ib ring test failed (-22).
Apr  5 15:01:41 medusa kernel: [31828.570534] thinkpad_acpi: acpi_evalf(STRW, vd, ...) failed: AE_NOT_FOUND
Apr  5 15:01:41 medusa kernel: [31828.570536] thinkpad_acpi: Cannot set adaptive keyboard mode.
```

**UPDATE**

Result of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`:   R13ET41W(1.15 )

**UPDATE 2**

I fresh installed Kubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.4) and the problem solved. Now after resume, I got a black screen, and this solved that: https://github.com/Pergravis?tab=projects

Comment: Related info I found: https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/ckkbej/t495_linux_avoid/

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Also, are your graphic drivers up to date?

Answer (score 0):

I switched from the X.org Nouveau opensource driver to the Nvidia proprietary driver and that solved this issue for me.  I was using Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 (Kernel 5.4) on a similar model Lenovo wielding a Nvidia GT218M [NVS 3100M] video card.

My experience was similar to yours after you installed 20.04.  However, instead of a black screen upon attempting to wake from Suspend or Hibernate, my screen would "wake" to various bizarre and nearly indescribable patterns such as alternating black and white 2s along with portions containing randomly colored pixels producing a certain visual "static".  One detail that was curious to me was that the mouse always remained perfectly visible and active. But the bottom line was always the same: the only option was a forced shutdown.

To switch the driver I opened the "Additional Drivers" application, which comes up as the Additional Drivers tab of the "Software and Updates" application.  There I saw this option.  It took several minutes for the application to load and install the driver.  I put it to the test immediately and, ugh, same old thing.  So, of course, I had to force shut down and I thought it was just another dead end.  However, during my next session I accidentally allowed the device to fall into Suspend (not again!), when, miracle of miracles, it woke back just as I had left it. : )  I would suggest to reboot before testing.

Comment: This did work for the most part, but there was always issues with screen refreshing after returning from a suspend.  I re-installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 and then had issues with trying to suspend after closing the lid.  Switching the display manager from LightDM to GDM3 solved all of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the display manager from LightDM (default on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04) to GDM3, really worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
```

During the GDM3 install process a screen pops up that allows you to choose GDM3 instead of LightDM. Choose GDM3!